# ReentrantLock condition wait get IllegalMonitorStateException in java

Tags: java, multithreading

My application will keep monitoring a folder, once it is not empty, it will wake up the worker thread. IllegalMonitorStateException will be thrown in the wait .

what is the reason ?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class LockTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String folder = "C:\\temp\\test";

        final ReentrantLock messageArrivedLock = new ReentrantLock();
        final Condition messageArrivedCondition = messageArrivedLock.newCondition();

        Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("worker thread is running");
                messageArrivedLock.lock();
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("worker thread is waiting");
                    try {
                        messageArrivedCondition.wait(); //Exception here 
                        System.out.println("worker thread wakes up");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (messageArrivedLock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                            messageArrivedLock.unlock();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();

        while (true) {
            long size = FileUtils.sizeOf(new File(folder));
            System.out.println("size:" + size); // 1000

            messageArrivedLock.lock();

            try {
                if (size > 0) {
                    messageArrivedCondition.signalAll();
                }
            } finally {
                if (messageArrivedLock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                    messageArrivedLock.unlock();
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you meant to invoke [`Condition#await`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await--), which will typically (as is the case here) have the same behavior you experienced with `Object#wait`.

> The current thread is assumed to hold the lock associated with this
>   `Condition` when this method is called. It is up to the implementation
>   to determine if this is the case and if not, how to respond.
>   Typically, an exception will be thrown (such as
>   `IllegalMonitorStateException`) and the implementation must document
>   that fact.

Presumably your `while` loop iterated once, released the lock inside the `finally`. On its second iteration, your thread doesn't have the lock, so calling `wait` will throw the `IllegalMonitorStateException`. Your thread needs to own the lock to invoke `await` on the associated `Condition`.

You can acquire the lock within the `while` loop.

Comment: I did it, acquire the lock within the first while loop, still same error.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard For the thread to return from the `await` call, the thread needs to reacquire the lock, so the lock will be owned by the thread when `unlock` is called in the `finally` block.

Comment: @user595234 Yes, but did you change `Object#wait` to `Condition#await`?

Comment: Why can't Object#wait be used?

Comment: @ed22 That's not the pattern being used here. A `Lock` object works with a `Condition`'s `signal` and `await`. For `wait` to be used, you'd need to use `synchronized` and `notify`.